# Android default group indicator ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm using an expandable list view where an user can select data.

The user can select either the group, either the child. To facilitate the distinction between the 2, I have a radio group with 2 options :

- Select the child : normal  expandable list (possibility to expand
  group and select child)
- Select the group : all the groups are collapsed, and the user can't expand the group

What I need, is to hide the group indicator on the second case, and then restore it when the first option is selected.

Here is my code :

```
rgLink.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if(checkedId == R.id.rb_link_subject){ //Here is the child mode
                mLinkType = LINK_SUBJECT;
                //elvSubject.setGroupIndicator(/*Here I need the default group indicator*/);
            }
            else{                                  //Here is the group mode
                collapseAllChildren();
                //The line below hide the group indicator
                elvSubject.setGroupIndicator(null);
                mLinkType = LINK_CATEGORY;
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm also using, for the group item :

```
style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
```

So basically, I just need a one line code to restore the default group indicator. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can obtain an attribute from the current theme:

```
 //obtain expandableListViewStyle  from theme
 TypedArray expandableListViewStyle = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{android.R.attr.expandableListViewStyle});
 //obtain attr from style
 TypedArray groupIndicator = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(expandableListViewStyle.getResourceId(0,0),new int[]{android.R.attr.groupIndicator});
 elvSubject.setGroupIndicator(groupIndicator.getDrawable(0));
 expandableListViewStyle.recycle();
 groupIndicator.recycle();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Whith that I can restore the group indicator when needed.

Comment: Can you please just explain how did you know that the group indicator style was the 0 index ? Is there a website or a file ?

Comment: `obtainStyledAttributes` returns a `TypedArray` holding the values defined by Theme which are listed in `attrs` [(link)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html#obtainStyledAttributes(int[])). In both cases we pass `attrs` array which length is 1, so result contains 1 element and this element has index 0 (it is index in the array, not the resource id).